# use multiple columns as variables with sapply

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a `dataframe` and I would like to apply a function that takes the values of three columns and computes the minimum difference between the three values.

```
#dataset
df <- data.frame(a= sample(1:100, 10),b = sample(1:100, 10),c= sample(1:100, 10))

#function
minimum_distance <- function(a,b,c)
{
  dist1 <- abs(a-b)
  dist2 <- abs(a-c)
  dist3 <- abs(b-c)
  return(min(dist1,dist2,dist3))
}
```

I am looking for something like:

```
df$distance <- sapply(df, function(x) minimum_distance(x$a,x$b,x$c) )
## errormessage
Error in x$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

While I can use ddply:

```
df2 <- ddply(df,.(a),function(r) {data.frame(min_distance=minimum_distance(r$a,r$b, r$c))}, .drop=FALSE)
```

This doesn't keep all of the columns. Any suggestions?

Edit: I ended up using:

```
df$distance <- mapply(minimum_distance, df$a, df$b, df$c)
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try mapply():

```
qq <- mapply(minimum_distance, df$a, df$b, df$c)
```

Comment: Which ine is the fastest? or more efficient?

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
do.call("mapply", c(list(minimum_distance), df))
```

but you can write vectorized version:

```
pminimum_distance <- function(a,b,c)
{
 dist1 <- abs(a-b)
 dist2 <- abs(a-c)
 dist3 <- abs(b-c)
 return(pmin(dist1,dist2,dist3))
}
pminimum_distance(df$a, df$b, df$c)

# or
do.call("pminimum_distance", df)
```

Comment: this is smart but a little less straightforward thank mapply.

Answer (score 6):

I know this has been answered but I'd actually take a different approach that takes any number of columns and is more generalizable using an outer approach:

```
vdiff <- function(x){
    y <- outer(x, x, "-")
    min(abs(y[lower.tri(y)]))
}

apply(df, 1, vdiff)
```

I think this is a little cleaner and flexible.

EDIT: Per zach's comments I propose this more formalized function that works on data frames with non numeric columns as well by removing them and acting only on the numeric columns.

```
cdif <- function(dataframe){
    df <- dataframe[, sapply(dataframe, is.numeric)]
    vdiff <- function(x){
        y <- outer(x, x, "-")
        min(abs(y[lower.tri(y)]))
    }
    return(apply(df, 1, vdiff))
}

#TEST it out
set.seed(10)
(df <- data.frame(a = sample(1:100, 10), b = sample(1:100, 10), 
    c = sample(1:100, 10), d =  LETTERS[1:10]))

cdif(df)
```

Comment: nice idea. my real dataframe is not a matrix however - could this be modified for use in a dataframe with text columns? something like outer(x,x,"-", drop_string=T)?

Comment: The function `outer` doesn't necessarily mean you're working on a matrix.  It just takes two vectors and a function and makes a matrix of all possible combinations for those two vectors.  Here I just supply the same vector (the row) to outer twice and the function subtraction `-` operator.  I added a bit to my solution to make a self contained function that acts on data frames and excludes anything that's not numeric.  `outer` can be very powerful I just wished I could remember to use it more.  As far as the drop_string = T?  No such luck but `sapply` with an `is.numeric` query works well.

Comment: very nice. I agree that outer is quite powerful and that for a larger matrix this would be the way to go rather than specifying each column or value.

Comment: Note: That because this answer is more generalizable it is likely that it also slower, not sure how much of an issue speed is (ie how big your data set is).

Comment: in this case speed is not a problem but I will keep this in mind. thanks tyler.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to write a function and then use mapply on the vectors:

```
 f1 <- function(a,b,c){
 d =abs(a-b)
 e =abs(b-c)
 f= abs(c-a)
 return(pmin(d,e,f))
 }

 qq <- mapply(f1, df$a, df$b, df$c)
```