# Apply function to heterogeneous rows of data.frame

Tags: r

Suppose that I have some (*non-vectorized*) function `foo`:

```
foo <- function (bar, baz, frobozz, frotz = 42) {
    if (frobozz) {
        frotz
    }
    else {
        bar * nchar(baz)
    }
}
```

It's a silly function, no doubt, but for the purpose of this question, take as a given.  (IOW, answers predicated on modifying `foo` are out of bounds.)

Also, suppose that I have the `data.frame` `df`, as shown below:

```
> df
  frobozz bar baz
1    TRUE   1   a
2   FALSE   2   b
3    TRUE   3   c
4   FALSE   4   d
5    TRUE   5   e
```

Now, each row of `df` can be regarded as a *heterogenous named list* (which I will henceforth abbreviate as *record*).

In fact, it's not difficult to cast any of `df`'s rows as such a record:

```
> df[1, , drop = TRUE]
$frobozz
[1] TRUE

$bar
[1] 1

$baz
[1] "a"
```

Moreover, the value in such a record for any of its named slots is of a type suitable as the argument of the same name in `foo`'s signature.

This means that I can use `do.call` to apply `foo` to any *single* row of `df`:

```
> do.call(foo, df[1, , drop = TRUE])
[1] 42
> do.call(foo, df[2, , drop = TRUE])
[1] 2
```

(Note that this works even though the ordering of `df`'s columns and the ordering of `foo`'s required arguments do not match.)

Now, I would like create a new column by applying `foo` to *every row* of `df`.

I had hoped that `apply` would be up to the task, but it fails:

```
> apply(df, 1, foo)
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 
  argument "frobozz" is missing, with no default
```

Of course, I could resort to something like this:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function (i) { do.call(foo, df[i, , drop = TRUE]) })
```

Is there a less ignorant-looking way to achieve this?

---

Here's a variation of this question that may be more tractable.

Consider the function `foo_wrapper`:

```
foo_wrapper <- function ( record ) {
    foo( record$bar, record$baz, record$frobozz )
}
```

This function is more flexible than `foo`, because all it requires is that its argument, `record`, have elements named `bar`, `baz`, and `frobozz`; it doesn't care about any other elements it may have.  Also, one can apply `foo_wrapper` directly to `df`'s rows, without having to resort to `do.call`:

```
> foo_wrapper(df[4, , drop = TRUE])
[1] 4
```

Unfortunately, `apply` fails with `foo_wrapper` as well:

```
> apply(df, 1, foo_wrapper)
Error in record$frobozz : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: See `?mapply`. Try `do.call(mapply,c(foo,df))`.

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078211/use-multiple-columns-as-variables-with-sapply) might be useful. See `?mapply` or its wrapper `?Vectorize` -- `do.call(Vectorize(foo), df)`

Comment: @Hack-R the `baz` column must be character in order of `foo` to work.

Comment: @nicola: thanks!  I had tried `mapply` before I posted, but pretty cluelessly: e.g. `mapply(foo, df)` and `mapply(foo, df[, c("bar", "baz", "frobozz")])`, resulting in errors similar to those I got with `apply`.  I wouldn't have thought of doing it through `do.call` in a million years.  It certainly works well, but I'm still a bit mystified byt the construct.  Would you mind posting your comment, and the reasoning behind it, as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `Vectorize` your function and then use `with()` to access the variables. For example your sample data...

```
dd <- read.table(text="frobozz bar baz
1    TRUE   1   a
2   FALSE   2   b
3    TRUE   3   c
4   FALSE   4   d
5    TRUE   5   e", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Then you can run

```
with(dd, Vectorize(foo)(frobozz=frobozz, bar=bar, baz=baz))
# [1] 42  2 42  4 42
```